# How to select values from Dropdown menu on a webpage:VBA

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
My code :

```
Sub login()
  Dim IE As Object
  Dim HTMLDoc As Object, HTMLDoc2 As Object
  Dim objCollection As Object

  Const navOpenInNewTab = &H800
  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "https:/com/1/19/login.esp"

  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop

  Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

  With HTMLDoc
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("USERNAME").Value = "xxxx"    'Entering credential
  HTMLDoc.getElementById("PASSWORD").Value = "yyyyy"
  End With


  Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementById("loginbutton")
  objCollection.Click

 'Second webpage

  Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop ' opening the second webpage

  Set HTMLDoc2 = IE.Document
  With HTMLDoc2
  **HTMLDoc2.getElementById("DEPARTMENTID").selectedindex = 1  'Drop down menu
  HTMLDoc2.getElementById("DEPARTMENTID").FireEvent ("onchange")**
  End With

  Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementById("loginbutton")
  objCollection.Click

End Sub
```

Q)**What code changes do I do to select Dwell_DF option Value 1567?**
The above code gives run time error '424' : Object required.

```
 HTMLDoc2.getElementById("DEPARTMENTID").selectedindex = 1  'Drop down menu
          HTMLDoc2.getElementById("DEPARTMENTID").FireEvent ("onchange")
```

The above line give the error.

In the first webpage I fill the login credentials then in the next page is that of the image pasted with this post. Here I want to change the value in the drop down menu.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. The value "1567" corresponds with the InnerText "Dwell_DF".

```
With HTMLDoc2
    .getElementById("DEPARTMENTID").Focus
    .getElementById("DEPARTMENTID").Value = "1567"  'You can also loop to find the text of the Option
    .getElementById("DEPARTMENTID").FireEvent ("onchange")
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.

```
Sub passValueToComboBox1()
   Dim ie  As Object
   Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   ie.Visible = True
   ie.navigate "http://your_URL_here.php"
   While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

   Set oHTML_Element = ie.document.getElementsByName("selectedReportClass")(0)
   If Not oHTML_Element Is Nothing Then oHTML_Element.Value = "FUBU7"

   For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
   Next
End Sub
```

Check out the link below for some other ideas of how to programatically interact with a web site.

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html